# Is it possible to lazy load a scrollview with multiple views?

Tags: android

So, lets say I've got my activity all set up, and it loads facebook names and users as well as some other things in a layout, and I just add a layout for each facebook user.

So I have a giant scrollview with a row for each user. Essentially a listview.

This can get up to 250 users, which causes a pretty huge loading time.

Now, the issue is, there is a **lot** to change if I want to convert this into a listview for the built in lazy loading. Is there any way to implement lazyloading into a scrollview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `ListView` and `Adapter` *is* lazy-loading in a scrollable view. It's the right solution, and it's pretty easy to set up. Doing anything else will just cause you more problems down the road. Take what the SDK gives you instead of trying to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can cache the result from your last loading, and display those first. Then you can slowly refresh each frame.